# AC-Current to ground without a closed circuit?

Tags: ground

I'm struggeling with the idea that there needs to be always a closed circuit for current to flow. The theory is that there shouldn't be a voltage drop across C2 and R2 and no measurable current at AM1 because there is no connection between ground and the rest of the circuit. So no AC current can flow.

That is all nice and good until I think about it in a physical way.

At the secondary coil electrons accelerate through the Lorentz force.

Charge beginns to build up at C1 and C2. The charge density at both cathodes should be the same.

Relation between charge density and electrical potential:
\$\Delta\phi\ = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}\$

Voltage should now build up between the cathode of C2 and ground (anode) because of the difference in charge density.

If we now think about the voltage/current relationship of the capacitor:
\$\ C * \frac{du(t)}{dt} = i(t)\$

Then there should be a measureable AC-current at AM1 even without a closed circuit?! Is that even possible?

Is there something critical I'm missing?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzgV9j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

*Continuously* flowing current requires a closed loop.

Current, or rather charge can flow without a closed loop. However, it will not flow continuously because once the potentials equalize the movement of charge will stop. (Think static shocks and antennas which are often dead end conductors).

There is such a thing as common mode voltage and common mode noise. These are perhaps the terms of the things you are referring to.

Continuously flowing current is like pumping air through a pipe. But you can also pump air into dead end pipe or tank. Once the pressure equalizes, the movement of air stops.

That said, I *think* your example is not quite accurate though (I don't really understand what it is you are trying to say). It sounds like you might be confusing the voltage between the TWO terminals of C1 (not relative to GND) and the voltage of C2's top terminal relative to GND.

Comment: Ok I get what you are saying! If C2 is trying to push or pull electrons out of the eath then we create a "pressure differential" that dosen't really like to exist. It's like C2 is fighting against the whole planet. That would still mean a really really small AC-Current would flow back and forth between earth and C2. So small infact that it would be negligible for engineering purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no current flow possible through C2 (no return path), the potential of the point between C1 and C2 is constant related to ground. At this common point there is indeed the same charge density for both capacitors, but while the other side of C2 experiences a constant charge density (and no current flow), the other side of C1 (which is the point shared with R1) experiences a continuously changing charge density and, therefore, current flow through C1.

In real systems you often have the primary side grounded, and the resulting loop allows so-called common-mode current through C2 via ground back to the primary.